# How to hide overflow of inline elements in a row using CSS?

Tags: html, css, overflow, inline

I have a case where I have multiple photos that I need to display in a row inline with each other. However if the length of the photos is greater than the screen width, I want the extra photos to be hidden (a photo being partially hidden is fine too) instead of them stacking and moving to the next row automatically. Is there a possible way to do this using css? This is what I tried so far (incorrect).

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="photo">Photo 1</div>
    <div class="photo">Photo 2</div>
    <div class="photo">Photo 3</div>
    <div class="photo">Photo 4</div>
    <div class="photo">Photo 5</div>
    <div class="photo">Photo 6</div>
</div>
```

```
.photo {
    display: inline;
    width: 100px;
    height: 75px;
}

.parent {
  width:400;
  height:100;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you share demo

Comment: @vadivela https://jsfiddle.net/3krub1zp/4/ .

When the width of the demo window is decreased, the photos stack, I want all of them to be in one row with the overflow hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using [`white-space:nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

```css
.parent {
  width: 400;
  height: 100;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.photo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #0f03
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="photo">Photo 1</div>
  <div class="photo">Photo 2</div>
  <div class="photo">Photo 3</div>
  <div class="photo">Photo 4</div>
  <div class="photo">Photo 5</div>
  <div class="photo">Photo 6</div>
</div>
```

2. using [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox):

```css
.photos {
  display: flex;
  width: 400;
  height: 100;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.photos > div {
  flex:0 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  border:solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="photos">
  <div>Photo 1</div>
  <div>Photo 2</div>
  <div>Photo 3</div>
  <div>Photo 4</div>
  <div>Photo 5</div>
  <div>Photo 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work and looks like the white-space property did the trick? Could you explain why/how this works? Are there any other methods to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
.photo {
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow:hidden;

}
```

It will hid overflow U just need to adjust the width of the photo width